# CSV Inventory file with add-member, create new lines instead of columns for objects

Tags: azure, powershell, export-to-csv

I'm writting an inventory script atm to retrieve information from my company's Azure Cloud. Everything is working just fine but one of the new requirement I'm facing is that I need to have results for certain information on new lines instead of additionnal columns.

Let me explain with an exemple and then a piece of my PS Code.

Let say I'm auditing my virtual machines. I want to retreive their name,location... all of these information are stored on a SINGLE line corresponding to the machine. Now, I need to add the installed Azure Extension to my file. Several extensions can be installed on a VM at the same time. For now, my script creates columns called "ExtentionX" (with X the number of the extension) and store each extension in a new line before continuing. My new need is to put these extensions in a single column with the name Extension and then on several lines. One for each Extension. The rest of the line as to be empty of course.

I tried things. The closest I got to a working result is to add my extensions to the final object independently from the rest of the information. But the script creates the number of lines required but the column is missing. Or, when I modify the script a bit, only the Extension column appears in the file...
Can anyone help me with this problem ? Thanks a lot !

Here's my current PS5/7 code:

```
$azureVMDetails = Get-azVM
$local_object = @()
foreach($azureVMDetails_Iterator in $azureVMDetails){
    
    $local_temp = new-object PSObject 
    $local_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Subscription" -Value $subIDinuse
    $local_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Location" -Value ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.Location | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "ResourceGroupName" -Value ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.ResourceGroupName | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "VMName" -Value ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.Name | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "VMId" -Value ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.VmId | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "VMStatus" -Value ($vm_state.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    
    if (($azureVMDetails_Iterator | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extensions).Id)
    {
        $vm_extensions_names = (($azureVMDetails_Iterator | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extensions).Id)
        
        $i=0
        foreach ($extension in $vm_extensions_names) {
            $local_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name ("Extension softwares installed"+$i) -Value ($extension | Out-String).split('/')[10] -Force
            $i++      
        }
    }
    else{
        $local_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Extension softwares installed" -Value "None"
    }
    
    
    
    $local_object += $local_temp
    Write-Host $local_object
          
    
}

if ($local_object)
{
    
        $local_object | Export-Csv "Virtual_Machines_details.csv" -NoTypeInformation 
   
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, I suggest you define a hashtable to store value the use `(New-Object PSObject -Property $local_temp)` to convert hashtable to object and export object to csv file

```
$azureVMDetails = Get-azVM 
$context=Get-AzContext
$local_object = @()
$local_temp=@{
  "Subscription"=""
  "Location"=" "
  "ResourceGroupName"=""
  "VMName"=""
  "VMId"=""
  "VMStatus"=""
  "Extensions"="" 
}


foreach($azureVMDetails_Iterator in $azureVMDetails){
    
    $vm_state=Get-azVM -ResourceGroupName $azureVMDetails_Iterator.ResourceGroupName -Name $azureVMDetails_Iterator.Name -Status
    $local_temp.Subscription=$context.Subscription.Id
    $local_temp.Location= ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.Location | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp.ResourceGroupName=($azureVMDetails_Iterator.ResourceGroupName | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp.VMName=($azureVMDetails_Iterator.Name | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp.VMId= ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.VmId | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp.VMStatus= ($vm_state.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    
    if (($azureVMDetails_Iterator | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extensions).Id)
    {
        $vm_extensions_names = (($azureVMDetails_Iterator | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extensions).Id)
        
        $i=0
        foreach ($extension in $vm_extensions_names) {
            $local_temp.Extensions= ($extension | Out-String).split('/')[10] 
            $i++  
            
            if($i -gt 1){
                 
               
                $local_temp.Subscription=""
                $local_temp.Location=""
                $local_temp.ResourceGroupName=""
                $local_temp.VMName=""
                $local_temp.VMId= ""
                $local_temp.VMStatus=""            
            }
            
            $obj =(New-Object PSObject -Property $local_temp)
             
            $local_object +=  $obj    
        }
    }
    else{
        $local_temp.Extensions= "None"
         $obj =(New-Object PSObject -Property $local_temp)
       Write-Host $obj 
    $local_object +=  $obj   
   }    
}
```

### [image]

**Update**

Regarding the issue, please set other properties' value before you set property Extension's vaule.

```
$azureVMDetails = Get-azVM

$local_object = @()
$local_temp=[ordered]@{
    "Subscription"=""
    "Location"=" "
    "ResourceGroupName"=""
    "VMName"=""
    "VMId"=""
    "VMStatus"=""
    "AzurePerformanceProfile"=""
    "DiagnosticProfileActivated"=""
    "BootDiagnosticProfileActivated"=""
    "OSImageTypeOrName"=""
    "OSversion"=""
    "AdminUsername"=""
    "NICName"=""
    "PrivateIP"=""
    "PublicIP"=""
    "PublicIPName"=""
    "AzureVMToolboxSoftwareInstalled"=""
    "Extensions"=""
    "MemberOfScaleSet"="" 
    "ManagedOSDisk"=""
    "DiskName"=""
    "DiskEncryption"=""
    "LinuxPasswordDisabled"=""
    "WindowsAutoUpdate"=""
    "WindowsPatchingMethod"=""
    "LinuxSSHKey"=""
    "ResourceLockLevel"=""
    "Tags"="" 
  }

foreach($azureVMDetails_Iterator in $azureVMDetails){

  ..........
   if ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.VirtualMachineScaleSet)
    {
        $local_temp.MemberOfScaleSet = ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.VirtualMachineScaleSet | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    }
    else{
        $local_temp.MemberOfScaleSet = "No"
    }
    $local_temp.ManagedOSDisk = ($os_disk_details_managed | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp.DiskName = ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    $local_temp.DiskEncryption = ($os_disk_encryption | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    if($azureVMDetails_Iterator.OSProfile.LinuxConfiguration.DisablePasswordAuthentication)
    {
        $local_temp.LinuxPasswordDisabled = ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.OSProfile.LinuxConfiguration.DisablePasswordAuthentication | Out-String).replace("`n"," ").TrimEnd()
    }
    else{
        $local_temp.LinuxPasswordDisabled = "Not Applicable"
    }       
    
    if($azureVMDetails_Iterator.OSProfile.WindowsConfiguration.DisablePasswordAuthentication)
    {
        $local_temp.WindowsAutoUpdate = ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.OSProfile.WindowsConfiguration.DisablePasswordAuthentication.EnableAutomaticUpdates | Out-String).replace("`n"," ")
    }
    else{
        $local_temp.WindowsAutoUpdate = "Not Applicable"
    }
    
    if($azureVMDetails_Iterator.OSProfile.WindowsConfiguration.PatchSettings.PatchMode)
    {
        $local_temp.WindowsPatchingMethod = ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.OSProfile.WindowsConfiguration.PatchSettings.PatchMode | Out-String).replace("`n"," ")
    }
    else{
        $local_temp.WindowsPatchingMethod = "Not Applicable"
    }
    
    if ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.OSProfile.LinuxConfiguration.Ssh.PublicKeys.KeyData)
    {
        $local_temp.LinuxSSHKey =($azureVMDetails_Iterator.OSProfile.LinuxConfiguration.Ssh.PublicKeys.KeyData | Out-String).split(' ')[1]            
    }
    else {
        $local_temp.LinuxSSHKey = "Not Applicable"
    }
    foreach ($resourceLock_Iterator in $resourceLock) {
        if ($resourceLock_Iterator.ResourceName -like $azureVMDetails_Iterator.Name)
        {
            $local_temp.ResourceLockLevel = ($resourceLock_Iterator.Properties.Level)
        }
        else {
            $local_temp.ResourceLockLevel = "None"
        }
    }
   
    if ($azureVMDetails_Iterator.tags)
    {
        $TagsAsString =@()
        
        foreach ($tag in $azureVMDetails_Iterator.tags.GetEnumerator()) 
        {
            $TagKey = ($($tag.Key) | Out-String).TrimEnd()
            $TagValue = ($($tag.Value) | Out-String).TrimEnd()
            $TagsAsString += $TagKey + ":" + $TagValue           
        }
        $local_temp.Tags = (($TagsAsString | Out-String).replace("`n","  "))
          
    }

    if (($azureVMDetails_Iterator | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extensions).Id)
    {
        $vm_extensions_names = (($azureVMDetails_Iterator | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extensions).Id)
        
        $i=0
        foreach ($extension in $vm_extensions_names) {
            $local_temp.Extensions= ($extension | Out-String).split('/')[10] 
            $i++ 
             
        
            if($i -gt 1){
                
                $local_temp.Subscription=""
                $local_temp.Location=""
                $local_temp.ResourceGroupName=""
                $local_temp.VMName=""
                $local_temp.VMId= ""
                $local_temp.VMStatus=""
                $local_temp.AzurePerformanceProfile =""
                $local_temp.DiagnosticProfileActivated =""
                $local_temp.BootDiagnosticProfileActivated =""
                $local_temp.OSImageTypeOrName =""
                $local_temp.OSversion =""
                $local_temp.AdminUsername =""
                $local_temp.NICName =""
                $local_temp.PrivateIP =""
                $local_temp.PublicIPName =""
                $local_temp.PublicIP =""
                $local_temp.AzureVMToolboxSoftwareInstalled =""
                $local_temp.MemberOfScaleSet =""
                $local_temp.ManagedOSDisk =""
                $local_temp. DiskName =""
                $local_temp. DiskEncryption =""
                $local_temp.LinuxPasswordDisabled =""
                $local_temp.WindowsAutoUpdate =""
                $local_temp.WindowsPatchingMethod =""
                $local_temp.LinuxSSHKey =""
                $local_temp.ResourceLockLevel =""
                $local_temp.Tags =""



                 
            } 
            $obj =(New-Object PSObject -Property $local_temp)
            $local_object +=  $obj 
        }
    }
    else{
        $local_temp.Extensions= "None"
        $obj =(New-Object PSObject -Property $local_temp)
         
         $local_object +=  $obj 
          
    }    


}
```

[image]

Comment: It's working thank you so much BUT i'm facing a small issue. All the command I insert in the CSV after my "Extension loop" are placed on the new line and not on the first line. Also, the columns are out of place because the following attributes are placed at the begining of the Excel worksheet instead of after the "Extension column". Any idea why ?

Comment: @tutruie Could you please provide a screenshot of what you want to do?

Comment: I want to the 3rd row (after extension) to be on the first line with its corresponding asset

Comment: @JilXu: I posted a reply under my own OP with my new code and images :)

Comment: @JilXu please see my update under my first post :)